# CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link '../../lib/libcaffe.so': function not implemented

Tags: python, cmake, caffe, google-colaboratory, openpose

I am trying to build openpose on google colab, and I have Cmake configuration was done, and when it comes to make, I used

```
make -j4 all
```

it popped an error, here is the error:

```
[ 84%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link '../../lib/libcaffe.so':  function not implemented
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Function not  implemented
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:2215: recipe for target 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make[5]: *** [lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
make[5]: *** Deleting file 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:240: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[4]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build' failed
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target   'CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is related to CMake or caffe, but rather the file system you compile on. I don't know 'google colab', but I think it is the operating system's file system does not support symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when I was compiling on NTFS
Check the file system. Compilation on ext4 goes smoothly
Hope this solves your problem